# Downloading image from URL in php?

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I am downloading image from url using php. here is my code

```
$filenameIn = $_POST['url'];

$contentOrFalseOnFailure = file_get_contents($filenameIn);


$byteCountOrFalseOnFailure = file_put_contents($filenameOut, $contentOrFalseOnFailure);
```

Its works fine. Now problem is that my image url is on my live server for example website name is `www.umair.com` and image address is `www.umair.com/image.jpg` now file_get_contents($filenameIn) is not working.

Error is:

> Warning: file_get_contents(www.umair.com/image.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: Based on the warning, you're missing `http://` Here's a quick fix `$filenameIn = "http://" .$_POST['url'];`

Comment: There is problem with web server configuration. Http:// is not adding. Btw thanks

Comment: Brother its working fine on my local pc by using xampp but on live server its not working ?

Comment: You'll need to ask the people who have given you answers. Once it's been solved, mark their answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> image address is `www.umair.com/image.jpg`

No it isn't, it is `http://www.umair.com/image.jpg`.  And, if that doesn't work (with the `http://`) then you must not have the fopen URL wrapper enabled.

Comment: Brother its working fine bt there is one more problem. My images were uploaded by ftp on my server . Now i am downloading image through URL from my server. I cant download image on the same server. Any other server its working fine. But problem is downloading from my server.

Comment: @umair Why do you want to download an image from the server you're on through the HTTP server?  Why not just open it directly?  In any case, you would need to give more information... what error are you getting?  Why isn't it working?  What do your web server logs say?

Comment: i am searching for same image from my data-bank for the testing purpose i give url of image that is already on my server. Than this image is not downloading through file_get_content. any other image from any server downloaded successfully. I dnt have permission for web server log

Comment: umair - did you check the filesystem configuration I outlined in my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the full pathname of the webserver.   (ie:  http://www.umair.com).

Note example #1 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Further, take a look at the runtime configuration for opening URL's: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php